# .htaccess removing the final "/" and ".html"

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have redeveloped a static html site in wordpress and am trying to map previous page address to the new wordpress compatible slugs using the htaccess file.

So I have figured out how to remove the ".html" of a requested url but also need to remove the remove the final “/”.

ie change "fred/fred1/fred2.html" to become "fred/fred1fred2" ...

Thanks for any suggestions...

Currently have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace this:

```
"RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]"
```

by this :

```
"RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\.html$ $1$2 [R=301,L]"
```